# #R how R compares numbers?

Tags: r, algorithm

Here's the codes:

```
2.9999999999999948933990 > 2.999999999999994893399
[1] TRUE
"20" > 2.999999999999994893399
[1] TRUE
"20" > 2.9999999999999948933990
[1] FALSE
"200" > 2.999999999999994893399
[1] TRUE
"200" > 2.9999999999999948933990
[1] FALSE
"20" > "200"
[1] FALSE
"20" < "200"
[1] TRUE
```

My mind is just boomed. Can anyone explain why adding a 0 matters? Also, which exact numbers "20" and "200" equal with?

Comment: strings are compared by string comparison.  Which comes first in the dictionary, "ba" or "baa" ?

Comment: I think this is a situation that confuses many R users - even experienced users - and I thought the example given was a good one. I would not mind a fuller explanation of the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `help("Comparison")`, numeric values are converted to character strings (for the comparison) if you compare them to a character string. Adding the 0 matters due to [accuracy of floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059).

In `help("as.character")` it is documented that

> `as.character` represents real and complex numbers to 15 significant
> digits

Now compare this:

```
sprintf("%.16f", 2.999999999999994893399)
#[1] "2.9999999999999947"
sprintf("%.16f", 2.9999999999999948933990)
#[1] "2.9999999999999951"

as.character(2.999999999999994893399)
#[1] "2.99999999999999"
as.character(2.9999999999999948933990)
#[1] "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that 2.999999999999994893399 and 2.9999999999999948933990 are not parsed as the same number.  The reason for this is likely the parsing algorithm that R uses.  I believe it goes something like this:

When you see a number containing a decimal point, ignore the decimal and read the number as an integer, then divide by the appropriate power of 10.

So 2.999999999999994893399 is read as 2999999999999994893399 and divided by 10^21.  But 2999999999999994893399 is too big to represent exactly, so it becomes 2999999999999994757120 after reading, and that becomes 2.9999999999999946709 after the division (since 10^21 can't be stored exactly either).

On the other hand, 2.9999999999999948933990 is read as 29999999999999948933990 and divided by 10^22.  Rounding is different, because the number is 10 times bigger:  the integer becomes 29999999999999949668352 and after division it is 2.999999999999995115.

Some of the numbers I show might be different on your system: most of this is handled at a very low level, and could be different depending on the system library and hardware.